# How to encrypt time machine backup on snow leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, time-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encrypt time machine backups](https://superuser.com/questions/236801/encrypt-time-machine-backups)

How can i do a time machine backup to an encrypted storage?

I wanna backup to a truecrypt volume or a dmg vault volume but when i mount it i cannot see it in time machine

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/236801/encrypt-time-machine-backups).

Comment: It's not a duplicato simply because of that solution it's no logner working!!!!