# Backup software for OSX

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup software for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/375/backup-software-for-mac-os-x)

I am searching a software like time machine but: free, which can backup external drives, and backup to any volume (for example Truecrypt volume)
Any hint?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backup software for Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/375/backup-software-for-mac-os-x) also check [Encrypt time machine backups](http://superuser.com/questions/236801/encrypt-time-machine-backups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) and been very happy with it.